# Platforming physics bouncing glitch C++

Tags: c++, physics, game-engine, game-physics

I am implementing some very basic platforming physics in C++ for a simple tile-based platformer. I am following the algorithm here (https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18302/2d-platformer-collisions) as exactly as I can yet I am still getting a weird glitch where the player bounces on a tile. I'm not exactly sure what is going on. The code is in C++ using SDL

```
void Player::update(vector< vector<Tile> > map) {
vector<Tile> collidingTiles;

x += xVel;
y += yVel;

boundingBox = Rect(x,y,16,16);

for(int iy=0;iy<MAPH;iy++) {
    for(int ix=0;ix<MAPW;ix++) {
        if (map[ix][iy].solid == true) {
            if (boundingBox.collide(map[ix][iy].boundingBox)) {
                collidingTiles.push_back(map[ix][iy]); // store all colliding tiles, will be used later
                Rect intersectingRect = map[ix][iy].boundingBox; // copy the intersecting rect
                float xOffset = x-intersectingRect.x; // calculate x-axis offset
                float yOffset = y-intersectingRect.y; //calculate y-axis offset
                if (abs(xOffset) < abs(yOffset)) {
                    x += xOffset;
                }
                else if (abs(xOffset) > abs(yOffset)) {
                    y += yOffset;
                }
                boundingBox = Rect(x,y,16,16); // reset bounding box
                yVel = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
if (collidingTiles.size() == 0) {
    yVel += gravity;
}
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (abs(xOffset) < abs(yOffset)) {
    x += xOffset;
}
else if (abs(xOffset) > abs(yOffset)) {
    y += yOffset;
}
yVel = 0;
```

In this code, if `abs(xOffset) == abs(yOffset)`, nothing happens, meaning that the player can enter a solid tile diagonally. Removing the second test should remove the issue and modify `y` if the algorithm has to make a choice:

Also, I'm wondering if you really want to reset the vertical velocity if a horizontal collision occurs. This also implies that gravity should still apply if the collision was horizontal (otherwise the walls and ceiling would be sticky).

```
int gravityApplies = true;//fix 2a

...

    if (abs(xOffset) < abs(yOffset)) {
        x += xOffset;
        xVel = 0;      //fix 2
    }
    else {             //fix 1
        y += yOffset;
        yVel = 0;      //fix 2
        if( yOfsset < 0 ){ // fix 2a
            gravityApplies = false;
        }
    }

 ...

 if (gravityApplies) { //fix 2a
     yVel += gravity;
 }
```

---

If you want elastic collisions, use `yVel = -yVel` instead of `yVel = 0` (and similar for the other direction). You can even do `yVel = yVel * rest` where `rest` ranges from `-1` to `0` (`-0.8` is a good choice) to get semi-elastic collisions.

Comment: Thank you for the gravity fix, however the issue of bouncing still remains, even when I change the else if statement to a simple else

Comment: @MattRoelle can you describe your issue? Fix #1 is to prevent getting embedded in a tile.

Comment: Do you want elastic collisions instead of inelastic collisions?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by elastic and inelastic, but essentially my issue is that the player continually bounces on a tile and won't rest on top of it

Comment: @MattRoelle how does that manifest? This should prevent the player from moving. If you want the velocity variable to be stable, you need to remember if the gravity should apply.

Comment: @MattRoelle reseting the y velocity when the player jumps should remove all effects of `yVel` fluctuating.